# how to update or refresh the content of tab panel in sencha touch

Tags: updatepanel, sencha-touch, tabpanel

i have list of items, while click the particular list item it will show the details of that item.. i have problem, for the first item click it shows the correct result but  while click the next item i am getting that particular item details but it showing the old item details.this is my code

```
 RadMobApp.views.patPanel = Ext.extend(Ext.Panel, {
    id: 'pathView',
    layout : 'fit',
 initComponent: function() {
        this.titleTxtc = new Ext.Component({
            cls : 'top_title_text',
            html: 'History'
         });
        this.backButton = new Ext.Button({
               text: 'back', 
               height:15,
               ui:'back',
               handler: function () {
                           controller.showPanel();
                            },
               scope: this
        });
        this.titleBar = new Ext.Toolbar({
            dock: 'top',
            cls: "top_tool_bar2",
            height: 42,
            items: [this.backButton, {xtype: 'spacer'}, this.titleTxtc, {xtype: 'spacer'}]
        });

        var tabs = new Ext.TabPanel({
            xtype:"tabpanel",
            id: 'tabpanel',
            renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
            width:400,
            height: 150,
            activeTab: 0,
            layoutOnTabChange: true,
            tabBar: {
            cls: "top_tab_panel1",
            height: 42,
            style: 'padding-left:2px;'
            },
            items: [{
                xtype: 'Panel1',    
                id: 'panel1',
                title: 'Panel1',
                height: 100
            },{
                xtype: 'Panel2',
                id: 'panel2',
                title: 'Panel2',
                height: 100
            },{
                xtype: 'panel3',
                id: 'panel3',
                title: 'Panel3',
                height: 100,
                listeners: {
                     beforeshow: function(p) {
                        scope: this;
                       /* var tabPanel = p.ownerCt;
                        var tabEl = tabPanel.getTabEl(prmPanel);
                        Ext.fly(tabEl).child('span.x-tab-strip-text', 
                            true).qtip = 'Tab is now enabled';    
                        Ext.getCmp('panel2').enable();  */          
                    }
                }
            }]
        }); 

        this.dockedItems = [this.titleBar];
        this.items = [tabs];
        RadMobApp.views.patPanel.superclass.initComponent.call(this);
    } 

});
```

how to clear the tab panel? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

try putting the config option

remoteFilter : true

to your store from which you are loading the data to the list.ie

```
new Ext.data.Store({
        model: 'Test',
        sortOnLoad: true,

        remoteFilter : true,
        autoLoad: true,
        getGroupString : function(record) {
            return record.get('FullName_FirstLast')[0];
        },
        proxy: {
            type: 'ajax',
            url : testUrl,
            reader: {
                type: 'json',
                root: 'test'
            }
        }

    })
```